# How to compare a parameter with an object in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, parameters, compare

Would anyone know how to compare an parameter with an object? I've been trying to do it following the instructions given in the last question here: http://prntscr.com/1zaq0y But, doesn't seem to wrork.

```
public class Classification
    {
        String changes;
        String rating;
        String description;

    Classification()
    {
        rating = "G";
        description = "Suitable for general audiences";
    }

    Classification(String must)
    {
        if(must != "G" || must!= "PG" || must!="M")
        {
            throw new NullPointerException ("Not equal");
        }
        rating = must;
        if(rating == "G")
        {
            description = "Suitable for general audiences";
        }
        if(rating == "PG")
        {
            description = "Parental guidance recommended"; 
        }
        if(rating == "M")
        {
            description = "Suitable for mature audiences";
        }
    }

    Classification (int num, String para)
    {
        if(num!= 13 || num!= 15 || num!=16 || num!=18)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not equal");
        }
        if(para==null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("String is null");
        }
        if(num == 16)
        {
            rating = "R";
            description = para;
        }
        changes = rating + num;
    }

    void printClassification()
    {
        print("Rated " + rating + ": " + description);
    }

    void derestrict()
    {
        if(rating == "M")
        {
            rating = "PG";    
        }
        if(rating == "PG")
        {
            rating = "G";
        }
        if(rating == "G")
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("G is least restrictive");
        }
        if(changes == "R18")
        {
            changes = "R16";
        }
        if(changes == "R15")
        {
            changes = "R13";
        }
    }

    Classification isLessRestrictive(Classification compare)
    {
        if(compare==null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException ("Classification para is null");
        }
        if(changes<compare)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between a "parameter" and an "object"???

Answer (score 1):

When comparing `String`s in Java, you need to use `equals()`.

For example,

```
if(must != "G" || must!= "PG" || must!="M")
```

Should instead be

```
if(!"G".equals(must) || !"PG".equals(must) || !"M".equals(must))
```

And

```
if(rating == "G")
```

Would look like this:

```
if("G".equals(rating))
```

Comment: Not to nitpick since it doesn't affect the answer but `if ("G".equals(rating))` is safer because rating can be null.

Comment: @Radiodef Mmm, good point.  I'll change the answer.